# How to allow movement while in animation (Unity)

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I have a game I am making where I want that the player has no animations until it hits a certain trigger. Then I want a short animation to be played, then it will stop the animation again.

[image]

To get this effect I have the above animator state machine attached to my player, and when the player collides with the trigger it plays the Halfway animation, then it goes back to the empty state. All of this seems to work fine at first but while my player is in this empty state loop thing, I cannot move it. I am using "rb.velocity = new Vector3(stuff);" to move my player, and when I disable the animator component I can move fine. I was wondering if

1. There is any way to enable movement while I am in this empty state,
2. There is some way to get rid of the entry transition entirely so I don't have to have the empty state at all, or
3. Pretty much anything else that would make this work :P

If you need more information let me know, I will try and help you help me as much as I can. Thanks!

Comment: Is root motion applied on the animation?

Comment: To be in one state of the animation or another should not affect the player controllers. Add the script you are using to move the character, that one that content "rb.velocity = new Vector3(stuff);"

Comment: Root motion is applied, and I will add the script tonight when I get home.

Comment: Sorry I forgot last night, but here is the code for my controller. I know it is kind of messy, forgive me. https://hastebin.com/icujiyubaw.cs

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre I am going to tag you guys because this is still an issue, and I posted my script above.